# Teaching high school mathematics after a pure mathematics PhD

Tags: phd, mathematics, teaching

I am currently a PhD student in pure mathematics. Since I began studying mathematics I hve wanted to pursue a career in academia, doing reserch and teaching at a university.

However, my interest in doing research has somewhat declined. I have a deep passion for teaching mathematics but I understand that it is not easy (or even possible) to teach mathematics in a university and make a career out of that without doing research. So I started to ponder the possibility of teaching high school mathematics, something I think I would be good at.

In my country it's not easy to find a job as a high school teacher and this is a seriously underappreciated job. My question is:

- In what countries could I expect to find a job as a mathematics high school teacher after completing my mathematics PhD?

Comment: I think it would be useful if you could be much more specific.  Where do you live now?  What languages do you speak?  What type of math do you expect to teach?

Comment: Different countries have different requirements. At least in the US, you should be certified to teach via a teacher preparation program in some states.

Comment: An option, with a sufficient English level, is to teach at international schools. And I suggest you try to get an internship, if you haven't taught yet. As it can be a very demanding job ...

Comment: In some US states, one can teach at a private high school without requiring any formal credential or certification; it's up to the school to decide if you are appropriately qualified.  I'm aware of some "elite" private schools that recruit fresh PhDs.

Comment: "I understand that it is not easy (or even possible) to teach mathematics in a university and make a career out of that without doing research." You understand wrong -- it is certainly possible to make a career out of teaching mathematics at a university without doing research.  There are at least 20 people doing that in my university alone.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I assume these are 'old school' staff who have been in the department for 10 years+? I can't see why a university hiring committee, who will have lots of candidates to choose from with more PhDs looking for jobs than ever, would decide to hire a person who said they won't perform research when they could hire someone who would teach and perform research?

Comment: @eurocoder: No, this includes new hires.  "I can't see why a university hiring committee, who will have lots of candidates to choose from with more PhDs looking for jobs than ever, would decide to hire a person who said they won't perform research when they could hire someone who would teach and perform research?" There is more than one kind of position for faculty to teach at a university.  Some departments (e.g. mine) need hundreds of courses taught per semester, so they hire some full-time teaching faculty in order to cover this load.

Comment: I'm in CA and my experience is 100% in agreement with Pete Clark's. Not only there's faculty positions dedicated to education, but there are some institutions where teaching postdocs are a thing. From what I've seen, at least in NA, specialising in math education at college level is a promising career path.